# functions coming from a perverse sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, perverse-sheaves

Let's take a scheme $X$ over a finite field $k$ and $f:X(k)\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$

What kind of condition do I need on $f$ if I want that it comes from an irreducible perverse sheaf on $X$?

Comment: What is a perverse sheaf on a scheme?

Comment: Also, what is $X(k)$ and what sort of morphism $f$ is?:)

Comment: f is a function on the set of $k$-points of $X$